# Text not showing in a label when clicking on a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am having trouble with a project I am working on that involves clicking on a button, and text is supposed to show up in a label box I created. I know this would be easier using a text box to show the text when I click on the button but my instructor wants us to use a label instead to show the text. I have debugged the project and everything says it is fine, but when I click on one of my buttons at the bottom, the text does not show up in the assigned label. Below is the code I am using. Maybe I am missing something. For example, when I click on customer relations button, it should show the department in one label, the contact name in the next, and the phone number in the next. I hope that is enough information

```
private void btnCustomerRelations_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDepartment.Text = "Customer Relations";
    lblContact.Text = "Tricia Smith";    
    lblPhone.Text = "500-1111";
}

private void btnMarketing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDepartment.Text = "Marketing";    
    lblContact.Text = "Michelle Tyler";    
    lblPhone.Text = "500-2222";    
}

private void btnOrderProcessing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    lblDepartment.Text = "Order Processing";    
    lblContact.Text = "Kenna Ross";    
    lblPhone.Text = "500-3333";   
}

private void btnShipping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    lblDepartment.Text = "Shipping";    
    lblContact.Text = "Eric Johnson";    
    lblPhone.Text = "500-4444";    
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it's just how you pasted it but there are no spaces in any of the method names (or arguments)

Comment: Rebuild Your Project , and Debug that Button Click Event by break Point , it must be easy to find the problem , may be confuse in button event and label event

Answer (score 2):

`Did the project compiled without any errors ?`.

By default every Event Handler in C# is declared as void,which I am unable to find in your code.Did you modify the Event Handlers generated by Visual Studio,if this is the case then the issue you are facing is because of this.

Let me explain what would have gone wrong;

Whenever you create a Event Handler for any control using the Properties Window of Visual Studio,for the sake of this explanation let me take `example of TextBox`.Suppose you have a TextBox (named as textBox1,which is default) and you subscribe to its `TextChanged Event` (to do that locate TextChanged event in the events window of Visual Studio and double click it,when you do that Visual Studio generates this for you;

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{

}
```

This is what we programmers call an `Event Handler`,now locate `Solution Explorer Window in Visual Studio` click on `Form1.Designer.cs` you will get a lot of code there,locate the line which says

`private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;`

where textBox1 is the control's name.Locate a plus sign above this point,click it and locate the following code;

```
// 
// textBox1
// 
this.textBox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(478, 0);
this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(359, 23);
this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

`PS:The Location , AcceptsReturn , Size and TabIndex property in yours might not be same as mine.`

Read the last line of this code,it says;

```
this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

where `textBox1_TextChanged is the name of event which must be same as that defined in Form1.cs.`If you modify this you'll get various compile time errors.

So now I guess you know what is the relationship between `Form1.cs`(main code file) and `Form1.Designer.cs`(code behind file).

In one line the conclusion is that make sure ;

`Any event handler function in Form1.cs` starts with **private void ....**,and the words after private void are exactly same as defined in the code behind file for that particular control.If you would like to read more about this stuff,have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5043/Step-by-Step-Event-handling-in-C).

Hope it would have helped you to solve the issue.Anything else left please inform me.

Comment: They actually do, there is a distinct lack of spacing in the code that was posted.  i.e. `privatevoidbtnMarketing_Click(objectsender, EventArgse)` which should be `private void btnMarketing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` you could be right, but the OP should be having issues compiling what they posted.

Comment: @MarkHall ,I guess they forgot to mention the compilation error,or what else could be the cause ?

Comment: Don't know they have gone silent. They actually need to step through the program to see what is happening. Anything we can come up with at this time is pure conjecture

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inserting an `Application.DoEvents()` statement at the end of each method? Sometimes forms are finicky about updating labels and that method will force the form to redraw itself.

Comment: There is no reason for using DoEvents in this scenario. I would rather see the OP use Invalidate() or Refresh()

Comment: Fair enough. As he had mentioned, using a TextBox would be easier but he is required to use labels. The only time I had used labels I faced issues and used [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/beea0c94-fce4-4f49-98e6-9c170e66cda9/change-label-text-during-run-) as my guideline which helped fix my code. I figured I would at least attempt to pass my limited knowledge along haha

Comment: The only reason that I commented the way I did, is the [`DoEvents`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html) method can lead you into trouble, I have used in the past and had problems with deadlocks. IMHO it is good not to get into the habit of using it, because it will jump up and bite you.

Comment: Again fair enough. I appreciate your comments and thanks for your advice! It is appreciated and I will be sure to remember it if I need it in the future! Thanks again :)